# golang testing method after each test: undefined: testing.M

Tags: go

I am trying to repeat example from [golang testing](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Main)

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestSomeTest(t *testing.T) {}

func TestMain(m *testing.M) { // cleaning after each test}
```

I want `TestMain` function to run after every test.

Running command `go test`

And the compiler says

```
./testingM_test.go:9: undefined: testing.M
```

So how to clean after executing every test?

Comment: If by "after each test"/"after executing every test" you mean each _individual test_, then that's **not** what `TestMain` is for. If instead you meant "after _all_ tests"/"after each 'go test' invocation"/etc, then perhaps you should make that clearer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check you `go version` output: this is for [go 1.4+ only](https://golang.org/doc/go1.4).

> The testing package has a new facility to provide more control over running a set of tests. If the test code contains a function

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M)
```

> that function will be called instead of running the tests directly.
>   The `M` struct contains methods to access and run the tests.

---

You can see [that feature used here](https://justinas.org/my-reason-to-be-excited-for-go-14/):

> The introduction of `TestMain()` made it possible to run these migrations only once. The code now looks like this:

```
func TestSomeFeature(t *testing.T) {
    defer models.TestDBManager.Reset()

    // Do the tests
}

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    models.TestDBManager.Enter()
    // os.Exit() does not respect defer statements
    ret := m.Run()
    models.TestDBManager.Exit()
    os.Exit(ret)
}
```

> While each test must still clean up after itself, that only involves restoring the initial data, which is way faster than doing the schema migrations.